# Android: OnClickListener in custom listView RadioGroup

Tags: android

I'm searching for a solution of my problem. I found a lot of similiar problems at stackoverflow, but I cannot apply it to my problem (maybe because I have not a lot of experience in android programing...)

The problem is the following: I have a custom listView adapter where the items looking like this:

The app has a SQLITE DB in the background. With a OnClickListener on the RADIO BUTTONS, I want to change the status of tables (tablename = text of .

The problem: OnClickListener influence other Items. If I click on first Item, the SQL Table of this item will be changed, but other SQL Tables too.

```
public class SpielerListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    // Globale Variables
    List list=new ArrayList();
    sql db = null;
    int status;
    String datum;
    String tabellenname;
    String pfad;
    Context con=null;

    public SpielerListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource){
        super(context, resource);
        con=context;
        db = new sql(context);
    }

    static class DataHandler{

        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;
        RadioButton UE;
        RadioButton E;
        RadioButton A;
    }

    public void add(Object object){
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row=convertView;
        final DataHandler handler;
        final SpielerListViewObjekt listViewObjekt;


        // Daten aus dem Objekt erhalten
        listViewObjekt=(SpielerListViewObjekt)this.getItem(position);
        status = listViewObjekt.getStatus();
        tabellenname = listViewObjekt.getName();
        datum = listViewObjekt.getDatum();
        //Bild anzeigen
        pfad = listViewObjekt.getFoto();


        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_spielerlistview,parent,false);
            handler=new DataHandler();

            handler.picture =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            handler.name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            handler.UE=(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.UE);
            handler.E=(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.E);
            handler.A=(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.A);

            row.setTag(handler);
        }
        else {

            handler=(DataHandler)row.getTag();
        }

        handler.name.setText(listViewObjekt.getName());
        //Set status from SQL Table
        if (status == 1)
        {
            handler.A.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (status == 2)
        {
            handler.E.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (status == 3)
        {
            handler.UE.setChecked(true);
        }

        //Picture
        File imgFile = new  File(String.valueOf(pfad));
        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            handler.picture.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }

        //On Click Listener picture
        handler.picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handler.A.setChecked(false);
                handler.UE.setChecked(false);
                handler.E.setChecked(false);

                db.setStatus(datum, tabellenname, 0);

            }
        });

        // setStatus will write 1, 2 or 3 as value into SQL Table

        handler.A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.setStatus(datum, tabellenname, 1);

            }
        });

        handler.E.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.setStatus(datum, tabellenname, 2);
            }
        });

        handler.UE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.setStatus(datum, tabellenname, 3);
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

}
```

What should I change to get a unique OnClickListener?

Comment: What is your SQL query?

Comment: Hi,
at the OnClickListener I use the setStatus, and this looks like this:

 public void setStatus(String mTraining, String mTabelle, int mStatus){
        db.execSQL("UPDATE "+mTabelle+" SET status = '"+mStatus+"' WHERE id='"+mTraining+"';");
    }

But I think this has nothing to do, that RadioButtons from other Items changes?